# Thymeleaf: Is it possible to use th:if when user changes the value?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a `<select>` input and another `<input>` on my page, and based on what the user selects in the dropdown, I want to hide or show the other input. However, both inputs tie back to the model, and it seems like that's stuck at runtime until the form is submitted.

Here's what I want to do, but when running the page, the second div doesn't show up even if I pick the right option.

```
<div>
  <label for="model">Model</label>
  <select th:field="*{manufacturer}" th:required="required">
      <option th:value="Ford">Ford</option>
      <option th:value="Tesla">Tesla</option>
      <option th:value="Lotus">Lotus</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div th:if="${car.manufacturer == 'Ford'}">
  <label for="gasType">Gas Type</label>
  <input th:field="*{gasType}" name="gasType" type="text" maxlength="5">
</div>
```

This tells me that `*{manufacturer}` isn't changing on user input, or else the page just isn't reacting to that change.

Is this possible to do with Thymeleaf, or do I have to use JavaScript?

Comment: Thymeleaf is rendered server-side so you'll need to do this in a script.

Comment: check for htmx, you will be able to do it without js

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using jquery/javascript. Since thymeleaf rendered at the server side, once the page gets load on your browser you only have html elements.
In order to achieve, try something like this -

1. Initially your second div will be hidden and you'd want to run a function each time user changes the select value.

   > ```
   > <div>
   >   <label for="model">Model</label>
   >   <select th:field="*{manufacturer}" th:required="required" onChange="hideShowForManufactr()" id="carManufctrOption">
   >       <option th:value="Ford">Ford</option>
   >       <option th:value="Tesla">Tesla</option>
   >       <option th:value="Lotus">Lotus</option>
   >   </select>
   > </div>
   > <div th:if="${car.manufacturer == 'Ford'}" style="display:none" id="fordDivId">
   >   <label for="gasType">Gas Type</label>
   >   <input th:field="*{gasType}" name="gasType" type="text" maxlength="5">
   > </div>
   > ```
2. Implement the logic to hide and show the div in your jquery function -

   > function hideShowForManufactr(){
   >
   > ```
   >      var selectCarMnfctr= $('#carManufctrOption').find(":selected").val();
   >      if(selectCarMnfctr == 'Ford'){
   >            $("#fordDivId").show();
   >       }else{
   >             $("#fordDivId").hide();
   >       }
   > ```
   >
   > }